# Virtualbox host and guest OS interaction

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Redhat Linux OS installed in one of my lab machines. Now, I am installing the virtualbox in the machine. I would be provided with the image of an operating system (Ubuntu), which I will be using as the guest OS. Now, I would like to configure the network so that the host OS and guest OS are able to interact among themselves. Also, I would like to configure the network so that the guest OS can access the internet too. I read through some documents in the virtualbox documentation and am confused on the MAC address concept. My question is,

- To accomplish what I have mentioned, do the MAC address of the host OS and guest OS need be the same?
- The Host OS is already in a network. So to make the guest OS available in the network, should I modify the hosts.allow, hosts.deny configuration file so that I can make the guest OS and host OS interact among themselves? In other words, if I choose DHCP in my guest OS would I be having problems in configuring the network for interaction between the guest OS and host OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VirtualBox VM will have a different MAC address than the host OS.

VirtualBox offers three different ways to connect a VM to a network, if I recall correctly. You can choose between an isolated network for VMs only, sharing the host's network connection and configuring a direct network connection between the VM and the same network the host is connected too.

Comment: I have a set of IP addresses available in my network. If I assign one of the available IP address to the guest OS and choose "Host Only", would I have configured the network correctly?

Comment: @Ramesh No, the option you would use for that case would be "Bridged".

Comment: Thanks Moses. I went through the article in this link. It explained the things clearly. https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1

Comment: @Ramesh: link dead